# using head -n1 to get first match of grep on osx

Tags: bash, macos, grep, head

I am trying to use `head -n1` to get just the first grep match (which is suggested a few places)

I expect this to work

```
$ printf "x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x" | python | grep -w 333 | head -n1
```

(pipe something that goes on forever into a grep command that will select a single line, and then take the first line from that output)

However, there is no output, and it never stops.

This works as expected: (take first line of infinite output, without grep)

```
$ printf "x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x" | python | head -n1
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

And this works: (grep the output and get a single match)

```
$ printf "x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x" | python | grep -w 333
333
```

(and never exits)

However, this combination doesn't give me what I would expect:

```
$ printf "x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x" | python | grep -w 333 | head -n1
```

(never prints anything and never exits)

Comment: As an aside, you can pass a string with literal newlines as an argument (rather than stdin) with `python -c $'x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x'`

Comment: I'm curious - why use shell to print a loop to pipe to python to execute instead of just writing the loop in shell: `x=0; while :; do echo $(( x+=1 )); done | grep ...`?

Comment: sorry - I am not actually doing this with that python loop - just used it as an example of something that goes on forever.  The same thing happens when you tail a file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `--line-buffered` option in `grep`:

```
printf "x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x" | python | grep --line-buffered -w 333 | head -n 1
333
```

As per `man grep`:

```
--line-buffered
     Force output to be line buffered.  By default, output is line buffered when standard
     output is a terminal and block buffered otherwise.
```

However note that command won't exit since you are running an infinite loop in python code.

If you want your pipeline to exit immediately after printing first match then use `awk`:

```
printf "x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x" | python |& awk '$1=="333"/{print; exit}'
333
```

Comment: right `printf "x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x" | python | grep 333 --line-buffered | head -n1` prints the result but still doesn't exit as you said.  I still don't understand why since `printf "x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x" | python | head -n1` does exit, and still has the infinite loop.

Comment: `head -n 1` exits because it has already printed given number of lines i.e. `1` line. But `grep` doesn't exit because we are not telling `grep` to exit after 1st match. That can be done using `awk` or `grep -m 1`

Comment: then why does `printf "x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x" | python | grep 333 | head -n1` exit?

Comment: It is because of the **buffering behavior** of `grep`. If you use `printf "x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x" | python | awk '/333/' | head -n 1` then it doesn't hang.

Answer (score 2):

[BSD grep on macOS > 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html) supports the `-m` option:

```
-m num, --max-count=num
     Stop reading the file after num matches.
```

So you can skip the head and use `-m1`:

```
$ printf "x=0;\nwhile True:\n x+=1\n print x" | python | grep -w 333 -m1
333
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
```